# JavaScript which displays the (image) logo of site

Tags: javascript, image

Hi I have this piece of JavaScript which displays the name of the website at the top of each page. However, I would like to replace this with the (image) logo of the site. I've had no luck in being able to implement this. please help, thank you.

```
$('.frr').each(function() { 
            var menutitle = $(this).attr("data-menu-title");
            if ( menutitle == "" ) {
                menutitle = "site.name.here";
            }
            else if ( menutitle == undefined ) {
                menutitle = "site.name.here";
            }
```

Comment: Why dont you just use a simple markup for this?

Comment: I agree with @LarryEliemenye...why can't use just place <img src="logo.jpg" alt=""> where the text for the site name currently is?

Comment: sorry i was being really thick, used background image in CSS to solve issue. long day. Thanks all.